# Leveldb: does read-after-write hazard exist?

Tags: asynchronous, leveldb

According to Leveldb's official documentation:

> By default, each write to leveldb is asynchronous: it returns after pushing the write from the process into the operating system. The transfer from operating system memory to the underlying persistent storage happens asynchronously.

So I was wondering whether read-after-write hazard would happen like this:

1. `db->Put(leveldb::WriteOptions(), "key", "value1");`
2. (After Step1 was done) `db->Put(leveldb::WriteOptions(), "key", "value2");`//asynchronously
3. `db->Get(leveldb::ReadOptions(), "key", &result);`//Is it possible that `result == "value1"` instead of `"value2"`?

I wrote a program to test it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <leveldb/db.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cassert>

using namespace std;
leveldb::DB* db;
leveldb::Options options;

int main()
{
    options.create_if_missing = true;
    leveldb::DB::Open(options, "test.db", &db);
    for(int i=0; i<10000000; ++i)
    {
        stringstream ss;
        ss << i;
        string sbefore = ss.str();
        db->Put(leveldb::WriteOptions(), "x", sbefore);
        if (!(std::rand() % 4))
        {
            string safter;
            db->Get(leveldb::ReadOptions(), "x", &safter);
            assert(sbefore == safter);
        }
    }
    delete db;
}
```

It seems that the assertion is always true in this case, but I'm not sure whether it is a general rule or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So I was wondering whether read-after-write hazard would happen like this:
>
> [Bad things]

No, you don't have to worry about that. Put()s are recorded in memory and are checked on every Get(); reads aren't directly from disk. See this part of DBImpl::Get():
https://github.com/google/leveldb/blob/dac40d25f6ce69c8b6685ab09f240cb63cfd5ab3/db/db_impl.cc#L1135